# can i use then function like this in nodejs.. xlToDb().then(() =>{

Tags: node.js, json, excel, function, file

I have a function to convert excel file to json. After that I have to read that json file and do some other activities. so first I called xlToDb method in my code and then I added a then function along with it like this ---- xlToDb().then(() =>{ })
 --but I got this error --TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. I did in nodejs. how can I acess the file that I converted using the function immediately after the function call

I tried then along with function too as shown below, but still I am unable to use then immmediatly after my code,

//pgm converts xl to json

```
const exceltojson = require('xlsx-to-json');
const fs = require('fs');
exceltojson({
    input: "testxl.xlsx",
    output: 'testxl.txt',// Don't need output
    sheet: 'Student_Details'
  },
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    else{
      console.log(result+'   result')
      console.log(result)
    }
    const newResult = result.map(obj => {
      const newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
        const newKey = key.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase();
        acc[newKey] = obj[key];
        console.log(newKey+'   newKey ')
        console.log('hello')
        return acc;
      }, {});
      return newObj;


     });
        fs.writeFileSync('testxl2.json', JSON.stringify(newResult));
      }
    ).then(function(result){

console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`.then()` is a property of a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Your function `xlToDb` seems to be returning `undefined`. Change the function's implementation to return a `Promise` to get this code working.

If the function is external and you cannot change it, then you can not use it like this.